# Music is crashing on Lumia 635. Any alternatives?

Tags: xbox-music, micro-sd, sd-card, lumia-635

When I first ran the Music application, it found a bit more than 720 music entries on my SD Card. Now, it takes a long time to "load," and when it does, it only crashes back to the home screen. Even when connected to a wireless network, it still crashes. Would someone mind helping me with it?

I've already looked at a couple free alternative apps: Modern Music; Extreme Player; and zbox. ZBox is taking more than 15 minutes to find my music right now, and I have the phone on a charger so it can keep going. The others crash about 8 seconds in as soon as I start up the apps.

Comment: Of course the Music app is not supposed to constantly crash. Have you thought about doing a hard reset? This might fix your problem.

Comment: Yep! Resetting to factory default fixed another problem that cropped up, too. Apparently it stopped responding to both the buttons and the touch screen, and all I could do was restart it to no avail, so I was forced to reset it by then. Haven't had problem since. Thanks for the input, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Soft restarting did the trick. Something messed up, then? Annoying, but workable.
Leaving this up in case anyone else encounters

Comment: Why don't you mark this as answer since it solved our problem. (Your questions still shows as unanswered)